# VBA -Distance between 2 strings

Tags: string, vba, parsing

I have written a simple macro to parse an e-mail that contains an HTML table. The table includes Brands in the first column, Countries in the second column, and a set of metrics in the following 6 columns. Based on the occurrence of a particular brand or country name in that e-mail, the macro performs various tasks.

This all works perfectly for the simple case, e.g.,

```
If InStr(strMsg, "Country1") > 0 Then <do xyz>
```

The script easily finds mentions of "Country1" in the table and performs the rest of the code as necessary.

Now I'm trying to implement for a situation where a row of this table contains "Brand1" in the first column AND "Country1" in the second column.

```
If InStr(strMsg, "Country1") > 0 And InStr(strMsg, "Brand1") > 0 Then 
 If (InStr(strMsg, "Country1") - InStr(strMsg, "Brand1") < 600) Then <do xyz>
```

The idea is (1) to check for the existence of both strings and then (2) use the character distance between them to confirm that they're in the same row of the table. This capitalizes on the fact the distance of the 2 strings, when they're in adjacent columns on the same row, is much smaller than the distance when they're in separate rows.

For some reason, the script always seems to execute when it finds both strings, regardless of which row they're on.

It's possible my distance (600) is too high, but there are well over 600 characters (incl. HTML mark-up) when the strings occur in different rows of the table.

- Is the code, theoretically, correct?
- When coming up with my 'distance,' should I be excluding certain special characters or mark-up?
- Any better ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a routine that will parse the HTML table and translate it into a memory-based array? Then your condition tests can be combined on a per-row basis without worrying about character-distance. If you write your HTML-to-array method correctly, it could handle any number of rows and columns in an HTML table and return an array of the same dimensions.

Comment: That is a brilliant idea and definitely cleaner, thank you... for what I'm doing, it's not really worth the trouble... yet!

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentionned by PeterT is more clean and efficient but this will do the trick :

```
If InStr(1,strMsg, "Country1") > 0 And InStr(1,strMsg, "Brand1") > 0 Then
    If (InStr(InStr(1, strMsg, "Country1"), strMsg, "</tr>") - InStr(InStr(1, strMsg, "Country1"),strMsg, "Brand1") > 0) Then '<do xyz>
```

The idea is that "" is the markup for the end of line in HTML table, so you first find your Country, the you start there to find the of line and the Brand, if it's positive, the Brand is on the same line!

Try this more elaborate way to do it :

```
Sub RunAllCombo()

Dim TR()
'you can create a loop here to change parameters
    TR = InHtmlTable(strMsg, "France", "PCM")

    For j = LBound(TR, 2) To UBound(TR, 2)
        If TR(0, j) <> True Then
            'nothing to do here, the combo isn't on the same row
        Else
            'Put your instruction here
        End If
    Next j


End Sub


Public Function InHtmlTable(ByVal strMsg As String, ByVal Country As String, ByVal Brand As String)
Dim Tc()
ReDim Tc(5, 0)
Dim StartS As Double
StartS = 1

While InStr(StartS, srtMsg, Country) > 0
    Tc(0, UBound(Tc)) = False
    Tc(1, UBound(Tc)) = InStr(StartS, srtMsg, Country)
    StartS = Tc(1, UBound(Tc)) + 1
    Tc(2, UBound(Tc)) = InStr(StartS, srtMsg, Brand)
    Tc(3, UBound(Tc)) = InStr(StartS, srtMsg, "</tr>")
    Tc(4, UBound(Tc)) = Tc(3, UBound(Tc)) - Tc(2, UBound(Tc))
    If Tc(4, UBound(Tc)) > 0 Then Tc(2, UBound(Tc)) = True

    ReDim Preserve Tc(5, UBound(Tc, 2) + 1)
Wend

    ReDim Preserve Tc(5, UBound(Tc, 2) - 1)


InHtmlTable = Tc

End Function
```

Comment: A good idea but this breaks if  Country1 appears on multiple consecutive rows (for different brands) and Brand1 isn't on the first row of that set. In that case, it's looking for "</tr>" on the first appearance of Country1 and potentially getting a negative result because Brand1 shows up on the following row.

Comment: Ok, I see what is the problem... I have a non elegant solution in mind and android in hands, so let me come back in few hours to propose a new version.